# Error creating bean . Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Now get this error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-24 15:55:37.651 ERROR 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryController' defined in file [D:\Max\JavaWorks\Diplom\OnlineShop\target\classes\com\maximmalikov\onlineshop\rest\DeliveryController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryService' defined in file [D:\Max\JavaWorks\Diplom\OnlineShop\target\classes\com\maximmalikov\onlineshop\service\DeliveryService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ordersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.maximmalikov.onlineshop.domain.Orders com.maximmalikov.onlineshop.repository.OrdersRepository.getByUserId(com.maximmalikov.onlineshop.domain.Users)! No property userId found for type Orders! Did you mean 'users'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.maximmalikov</groupId>
    <artifactId>onlineshop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>onlineshop</name>
    <description>Onlineshop project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The main class, the class of service and the class of the controller with the repository:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class OnlineshopApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OnlineshopApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Repository
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders,Long> {

    Orders getByOrderNumber(long orderNumber);

    Orders getByOrderDate(Date orderDate);

    Orders getByGoodsProductId(Goods productId);

    Orders getByGoodsProductName(Goods productName);

}

   @Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class OrdersService {

    private final OrdersRepository ordersRepository;

    private final GoodsRepository goodsRepository;

    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    private final DeliveryRepository deliveryRepository;

    private OrdersDTO fromOrders(Orders order) {
        if (order != null) {
            return OrdersDTO.builder()
                    .orderNumber(order.getOrderNumber())
                    .orderDate(order.getOrderDate())
                    .orderTime(order.getOrderTime())
                    .orderStatus(order.getOrderStatus())
                    .paymentMethod(order.getPaymentMethod())
                    .goods(order.getGoods() != null
                            ? order.getGoods().stream()
                            .map(Goods::getProductId)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                            : null)
                    .users(order.getUsers() != null
                            ? order.getUsers().stream()
                            .map(Users::getUserId)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                            : null)
                    .delivery(order.getDelivery().getOrderNumber())
                    .build();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Orders fromDTO(OrdersDTO ordersDTO) {
        if (ordersDTO != null) {
            return Orders.builder()
                    .orderNumber(ordersDTO.getOrderNumber())
                    .orderDate(ordersDTO.getOrderDate())
                    .orderTime(ordersDTO.getOrderTime())
                    .orderStatus(ordersDTO.getOrderStatus())
                    .paymentMethod(ordersDTO.getPaymentMethod())
                    .goods(ordersDTO.getGoods() != null
                            ? goodsRepository.findAllById(ordersDTO.getGoods())
                            : null)
                    .users(ordersDTO.getUsers() != null
                            ? usersRepository.findAllById(ordersDTO.getUsers())
                            : null)
                    .delivery(ordersDTO.getDelivery() > 0L
                            ? deliveryRepository.getOne(ordersDTO.getDelivery())
                            : null)
                    .build();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<OrdersDTO> getAllOrders() {
        return ordersRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(this::fromOrders)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Transactional
    public OrdersDTO addOrder(OrdersDTO ordersDTO) {
        if (!ordersRepository.existsById(ordersDTO.getOrderNumber())) {
            return fromOrders(ordersRepository.saveAndFlush(fromDTO(ordersDTO)));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteByOrderNumber(long orderNumber) {
        if (ordersRepository.existsById(orderNumber)) {
            ordersRepository.deleteById(orderNumber);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public OrdersDTO updateOrder(OrdersDTO ordersDTO) {
        if (ordersRepository.existsById(ordersDTO.getOrderNumber())) {
            Orders ordersTemp = ordersRepository.getOne(ordersDTO.getOrderNumber());
            ordersTemp.setOrderDate(ordersDTO.getOrderDate());
            ordersTemp.setOrderTime(ordersDTO.getOrderTime());
            ordersTemp.setOrderStatus(ordersDTO.getOrderStatus());
            ordersTemp.setPaymentMethod(ordersDTO.getPaymentMethod());
            return fromOrders(ordersRepository.saveAndFlush(ordersTemp));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public OrdersDTO getByOrderNumber(long orderNumber) {
        if (ordersRepository.existsById(orderNumber)) {
            return fromOrders(ordersRepository.getByOrderNumber(orderNumber));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public OrdersDTO getByOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        return fromOrders(ordersRepository.getByOrderDate(orderDate));
    }

    public OrdersDTO getByProductId(Goods product) {
        return fromOrders(ordersRepository.getByGoodsProductId(goodsRepository.getByProductId(product.getProductId())));
    }

    public OrdersDTO getByProductName(Goods product) {
        return fromOrders(ordersRepository.getByGoodsProductName(goodsRepository.getByProductName(product.getProductName())));
    }

}

   @RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class OrdersController {

    private final OrdersService ordersService;
    private final GoodsRepository goodsRepository;


    @GetMapping
    public List<OrdersDTO> getAll() {
        return ordersService.getAllOrders();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<OrdersDTO> addOrder(@RequestBody OrdersDTO ordersDTO) {
        OrdersDTO ordersDTO1 = ordersService.addOrder(ordersDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ordersDTO1);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{order_number}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteOrder(@PathVariable(value = "order_number") long orderNumber) {
        try {
            ordersService.deleteByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
    }

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<OrdersDTO> updateOrder(@RequestBody OrdersDTO ordersDTO) {
        OrdersDTO ordersDTO1 = ordersService.updateOrder(ordersDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ordersDTO1);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{order_number}")
    public ResponseEntity<OrdersDTO> getOrderByNumber(@PathVariable(value = "order_number") long orderNumber) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ordersService.getByOrderNumber(orderNumber));
    }

    @GetMapping("/{order_date}")
    public ResponseEntity<OrdersDTO> getOrderByDate(@PathVariable(value = "order_date") Date orderDate) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ordersService.getByOrderDate(orderDate));
    }

    @GetMapping("/goods/{product_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<OrdersDTO> getOrderByProductId(@PathVariable(value = "product_id") long productId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ordersService.getByProductId(goodsRepository.getByProductId(productId)));
    }

    @GetMapping("/goods/{product_name}")
    public ResponseEntity<OrdersDTO> getOrderByProductName(@PathVariable(value = "product_name") String productName) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ordersService.getByProductName(goodsRepository.getByProductName(productName)));
    }


}
```

Configuring the Database Connection in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlineshopbd?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=malikovmaxim1997

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view = true
```

The project was configured with Spring-Boot, and the configurations are all configured solely by means of annotations, that is, I've seen a lot of same problems on the Internet, but all the bin settings are configured in xml files.  This approach is not suitable for this project.  Help to understand this error, and how to adjust in that case bins, without using xml.

Comment: try using `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;` at your service.

Comment: Here this approach is useless, because I do not need to redefine the interface methods, and return the entitymanager, because I refer to repositories through DТO that directly access models.

Comment: Show us your class GoodsRepository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at you pom.xml I noticed you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as well as `hibernate-entitymanager version 5.2.17.Final`

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa will pull in all the hibernate dependencies you need

So remove this dependency from pom.xml and it should work

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Edit 1:**

Change this

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class CharacteristicsService {

    private final GoodsRepository goodsRepository;
```

to

```
 @Service
 public class CharacteristicsService {

      @AutoWired
      private final GoodsRepository goodsRepository;
```

and also

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class OnlineshopApplication {
```

I don't know why you have excluded @EnableAutoConfiguration but you can try this

Comment: I added this addiction just , because in programm did not find the entity manager. Removing the dependency, the error still remains the same.

Comment: Can you try removing @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.maximmalikov.onlineshop.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement  from OnlineshopApplication class. As SpringBoot will add these configuration by default once it finds spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in pom.

Comment: This is all clear.  I began to add annotations as the autoconfiguration began to fail to appear.  Initially, there was only @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: Reason to use SpringBoot is it handles lot of configuration automatically. I too have SpringBoot setup with Repository but I have only @SpringBootApplication.  You need to see what error you get after removing and debug accordingly. Am sure you have messed configuration some where.

Comment: I removed two annotations that you advised, and now I've issued a different similar error. I edit my question and you will see

Comment: Unfortunately, your changes did not help (I can drop the repository with the source code if necessary

Comment: I removed the @EnableAutoConfiguration exceptions, But for some reason the bins fail anyway

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked, thank you all for your help.  I solved the problem by removing the @EnableAutoConfiguration exceptions.  And in OrdersRepository there was an incorrectly written method, which needed to be removed from the service and the controller, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

dude, it looks like ur missing some spring annotation, in my case it was a simple @Repository marker on my repository class...

I have found some information here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-unsatisfied-dependency

have another situation when u have more than one bean that satisfy an operation..
for this case u can add this annotation in ur application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.yourpackage"}) //this line**
public class SpringDependenciesExampleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDependenciesExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```